# How does one draw a parallelepiped in Mathematica?

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

I'm a bit new to the application, and I'm not sure how to draw a parallelepiped in *Mathematica*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After version 9: [`Parallelepiped`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelepiped.html).

```
Graphics3D[Parallelepiped[{0, 0, 0}, {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

---

Version 9 or before. Right from the documentation of [`ShearingMatrix`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0dczko9v3s0i-gc95ov), that is a `GeometricTransformation`:

```
Graphics3D[{GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, Cuboid[]}, 
   ShearingMatrix[Pi/4, {1, 0, 0}, {-1, 1, 0}]]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

A dynamic manipulator to understand arguments:

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{
   GeometricTransformation[{Opacity[.85], Red, Cuboid[]}, 
    ShearingMatrix[a, dir, {x, y, z}]]
   }, FaceGrids -> {{-1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, -1}}, Axes -> True, 
  Boxed -> False, BoxRatios -> 1, SphericalRegion -> True],

 {{a, Pi/4}, -Pi/2, Pi/2, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{dir, {0, 1, 0}, "direction"}, {{1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}},
 {{x, -1}, -1, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{y, 1}, -1, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 {{z, 0}, -1, 1, .1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 ControlPlacement -> Left
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]